# Error on my iFrame FB page: HTTP Error 405

Tags: facebook, http, iframe

I keep getting this error on my iFrame FB page :

> HTTP Error 405

Comment: You really need to give more detail, a 405 is **method not allowed** [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) You need to figure what wrong request you're making. You could maybe put some relevant code or give us an idea of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Does the URL you specified for the iFrame work by itself out of the iframe?

Comment: DMCS...thanks... yes it does... http://www.lifegear.com/facebook/facebookwelcome.html

Comment: Ok, the http versions works, but the https version does not load at all.  Check your SSL cert on your server to make sure it is installed correctly.

Comment: DMCS... yes the ssl was incorrect.. fixed.  Now I've got the website showing up instead of the iframe.  I've been trying to learn this since FB has started undergoing their new changes.  Therefore finding current tutorials has been difficult.

Comment: You may want to start a new question since this one has been answered.